# Anchor tag helpers do not reuse the current route values

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.2, asp.net-core-routing

Currently I am using ASP.NET Core 2.2 MVC to build my application, having a conventional route of template :

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "default",
    template: "{culture:required}/{area:slugify:exists}/{controller:slugify}/{action:slugify}",
    defaults: new
    {
        area = "Home",
        controller = "Home",
        action = "Index"
    });
```

In `/Areas/Home/Views/Home/Index.cshtml`, I tried to write the following and expect something like "http://localhost/en-US/Home/Home/AboutUs" would be generated, but it just does not work:

```
<a 
   asp-area="Home" 
   asp-controller="Home" 
   asp-action="AboutUs">
    About Us
</a>
```

Instead, specifying the culture explicitly works:

```
<a asp-area="Home" 
   asp-controller="Home" 
   asp-action="AboutUs" 
   asp-route-culture="en-US">
    About Us
</a>
```

However, since my site contains tons of links, I do not want to pollute all  tags with `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name`. Is there a smart way to force it inheriting the current route value if not explicitly specified by `asp-route-culture`?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "us_english_products",
    template: "en-US/Products/{id?}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Products", action = "Details" },
    dataTokens: new { locale = "en-US" });
```

I think you are looking for this.  Its located on the docs under

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.2#differences-from-earlier-versions-of-routing

So you don't have to hard code the route on each link but you can setup the route so that it takes it into account.  It appears you name `locale` whatever you want so if you want to name `culture` you can.

Comment: Isn't that mean if I have 3 locales for my app, I gotta register each route 3 times for each locale?

Comment: With your approach I need to hard code all locales into startup.cs, where I may actually add locales in runtime

Comment: while it is 1.1.0 it might help and the docs that support for 2.2 are almost identical https://andrewlock.net/url-culture-provider-using-middleware-as-mvc-filter-in-asp-net-core-1-1-0/. ultimately yes you have to eventually hard-code for the languages you will support.